# TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable. Working on text-based adventure game

Tags: python

I'm creating a text based adventure game as a hobby project and encountered this problem when implementing one of the possible interactions in the game world

Other functions using the move[0] thing work as shown bellow but here it just doesn't seem to want to work.

```
def gamehelp():
  if move[0] == 'help':
    showInstructions()
```

This is what the error refers to

```
def move():
  move = ''
  while move == '':  
    move = input('>')

  move = move.lower().split()

  if move[0] == 'go':
    global currentRoom
    if move[1] in rooms[currentRoom]:
      if currentRoom == 'Corridor' and move[1] == 'west' and not 'key' in str(inventory):
        print('This Door is Locked!')
      else:
        currentRoom = rooms[currentRoom][move[1]]
    else:
        print('You can\'t go that way!')
```

Here is where i have the move variable defined

```
while True:

  showStatus()
  move()
  gamehelp()
  itemPickup()
  look()
```

And here i call upon the different functions, where gamehelp() and look() have just been implemented.

The output which i was expecting was for it to display the showInstructions() function when i type 'help' into the game but it comes back with this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 139, in <module>
    gamehelp()
  File "main.py", line 72, in gamehelp
    if move[0] == 'help':
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Your string `move` shadows  the name of your function `def move()`. Rename one of them. Also in the context of `gameHelp` only the function name `move` is visible.

Comment: `move` is your function. _Inside_ that function there is a variable also called `move`. Outside that, `move` means the function itself.

Comment: In your `while` loop, you're just calling your function. But you should also assign it to a variable to access the output. That being said, you would need your `move()` function to return something rather than just printing out text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your gamehelp function you have no parameters, but it's expecting `move` to be checked. You would need to accept, and pass move as a parameter like
`gamehelp(move)`

With the function changed to

```
def gamehelp(param):
    if param[0] == 'help':
        showInstructions()
```

This should fix that error. I will now do a few unrequested code recommendations. Feel free to ignore these if you wish, but I think you'll have problems down the line if you don't at least heed them.

Firstly, the method `gamehelp()` is somewhat pointless if that is the entire method. If you're calling `gamehelp`, you may as well call `showInstructions()` instead. You should be checking if you're calling `gamehelp` before just running the method and extend that to everything. I'm happy to help you try and sort that out if you like, but your current method will not scale and will almost certainly bring around bugs, because you will have to check every single method whenever there's a problem in your `while` loop.

Your `move` function can also be refactored quite a bit. I would also not recommend using a variable with the same name of the method, because it can get confusing when you use first class functions.

I have refactored just the move variable as an example. Explanation below:

You're not actually adding to the move variable, it's only taking the LAST thing the user input. If you do want to add to the move variable, use the += operator or the string join() method. I'm guessing this is a bug you don't know about yet or else this would look different. At any rate this does the exact same thing, except that it only takes the first thing the user input. The way you did it before also meant that the user had to enter a blank line by itself. I think In order to have it actually do anything You should also have a space after the more than sign, it'll look cleaner when the user is typing. Now you should be able to do `>go west` instead of `>go >west >`

```
def move():
    move = input('> ').lower().split()
...
```

There are lots of other problems that I can foresee eventually coming to fruition in your code as well. For example, what if you want a named corridor? Then this would fail because it's just checking `currentRoom`, which is a string. You would be better off using a class that has a room TYPE, or even different types of classes for each room (which is probably unnecessary). You could then do `currentRoom.type` and have zero contention on what type of room it is. This could carry over to which ways the player can move, like having a method check whether or not west is an option and/or if they have a key, and/or if west is a door... etc.

Let's take the players inventory for example. If you're just checking whether or not they have a key, how will you handle multiple, different keys? What if there's an occurrence of key in the inventory (since it's a string), or has absolutely nothing to do with keys? The answer is to use objects and arrays. Make a player class with their inventory/statuses/etc. Then you can make their inventory an array/dict/whatever floats your boat, and finally check for them having a specific item instead of just 'key'. This would also allow you to actually use up the key (which you didn't do, but may have been on purpose) by removing it from the array/dict/whatever.

You are going to have lots of repeated code, or errors unless you use something akin to classes. Even in this short snippet I can already see problems or future problems.

**TL;DR:  Use OOP. Classes are your friends.**

P.S. I am more than happy to help you if you like. I hope that this was helpful :>

P.P.S. Unless your goal is to make a text adventure engine, you may want to use one that's already been made.

Comment: currentRoom is used as a variable to look into a dictionary 'rooms'. And thank you very much. If i do have any further questions ill be posting them on here.